# How to pass Selenium authentication for testing?

Tags: java, selenium, authentication, testing, webdriver

I want to pass authentification form for testing with Selenium.
I want to omit passing user credentials in URL.

***How can I do it with Selenium?***

Example of authorization form is below: [auth form example](https://postman-echo.com/basic-auth)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For passing this authorisation you have few choices:

- [BrowserMob Proxy](https://bmp.lightbody.net)

It has API for basic auth, with something like:

> server.autoBasicAuthorization("", "username", "password");

Example:

```
import net.lightbody.bmp.proxy.ProxyServer;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Proxy;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

public class ProxyServerBasicAutorizationTest {

    private ProxyServer server;
    private WebDriver driver;

    @Before
    public void startProxy() throws Exception {
        server = new ProxyServer(4444);
        server.start();
        server.autoBasicAuthorization("", "username", "password");
        Proxy proxy = server.seleniumProxy();

        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);

        driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
    }

    @Test
    public void testAccessProtectedSite() throws Exception {
        driver.get("https://example.com");
        driver.findElement(By.className("sign-out"));
    }

    @After
    public void stopProxyServer() throws Exception {
        driver.quit();
        server.stop();
    }
}
```

However, I knew that it worked only with basic authorization.

- [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/)
  The problem here is that different browsers make windows in a different way. 
  For Firefox your script can be like the following:

  Local $classForBasicAuthWindow = "[CLASS:MozillaDialogClass]";

  ;wait auth window appearance 10 sec
  WinWait($classForBasicAuthWindow, "", 10)

  If WinExists($classForBasicAuthWindow) Then
    WinActivate($classForBasicAuthWindow)

  ;user name
    Send($CmdLine[1] & "{TAB}");

  ;user password
    Send($CmdLine[2] & "{ENTER}");
  EndIf

You have to convert `.au3` file to `.exe` file (if you have Windows OS) and use it during the test. You can use `Aut2exe` for it.

You have to launch `.exe` file before opening the page by browser:

```
public class AutoItBasicAutorizationTest {

    private final String username = "username";
    private final String password = "password";

    @Test
    public void testBasicAuthenticationFirefox() throws Exception {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        File autoIt = new File("src/test/resources/auth.exe");

        // run exe file with passing user credentials
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
                autoIt.getAbsolutePath() + " "
                                  + username + " " + password);

        driver.get("https://example.com");
        driver.findElement(By.className("sign-out"));
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

For writing script for multiple browsers your script should be something like:

```
$timeoutSec = 10;
$lookingSec = 0;
While $lookingSec < $timeoutSec
    ;Firefox or InternetExplorer or Chrome
    If WinExists("[CLASS:MozillaDialogClass]") _
        Or WinExists("[TITLE:Windows Security; CLASS:#32770]") _
            Or WinExists("[CLASS:Chrome_WidgetWin_1]", _
                                    "Authentication Required") Then
                ;user name
                Send($CmdLine[1] & "{TAB}"); 
                ;password
                Send($CmdLine[2] & "{ENTER}"); 
                Exit;
    EndIf
    sleep(1000)
    $lookingSec += 1;
WEnd
```

However, it depends on browsers versions and settings. Just check AutoIt Window Info.